# Angular pipe not working with iFrame bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Tags: angular, iframe, pipe

I cant get pipe to work properly with iFrame. I am trying to display a web component within an iFrame in my angular app. When I decorate the iFrame with my pipe "sanitizeUrl", I see my web app embedded in my iFrame inception style. If I remove it I get the following error, but I can see the correct web component displayed. What is my issue?

'Error: NG0904: unsafe value used in a resource URL context'

I am displaying a basic iFrame on a component
`<iframe (load)="isLoaded()" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe | sanitizeUrl"></iframe>`

Here is my pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser;

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeUrl' })
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url): SafeResourceUrl {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
`
```

Component

```
public urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private safeUrl: SafeUrlPipe
  ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.swipeSvc.getJwt('EmployeeSSO', clientCode, personId).subscribe(resp => {
      this.urlSafe = this.safeUrl.transform(
        `${this.url}${resp.jwt}&enclosed=1&compact=1&showess=0`
      );
    });
  }
'
```

Expected to see the actual web component embedded in my iFrame

---

Here is the module that got this working for me....
https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-pipe?activeTab=readme